# Tracking fast forward/ rewind in tvos

Tags: objective-c, avplayer, tvos, avplayerviewcontroller

Apple's tvos `AVPlayerViewController` allows user to fast forward/rewind by pressing down on the rightmost/leftmost end of the siri remote. Is there any delegate method to track this. I did come across the following method but its only good enough to track drag/drop seeks or seek forwards by 10 seconds. Is there any other way to track fast forwards, short of keeping track of avplayeritems `currentTime` property?

```
- (void)playerViewController:(AVPlayerViewController *)playerViewController
willResumePlaybackAfterUserNavigatedFromTime:(CMTime)oldTime
                      toTime:(CMTime)targetTime
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to get that information back from AVPlayerViewControllerDelegate.

But due to the fact that AVPlayerViewController, at then, is using an injected instance of AVPlayer internally... you could create your custom subclass of AVPlayer to keep track of that usage.

```
class ViewController: AVPlayerViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        play(stream: URL(string: "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")!)
    }

    // MARK: - Private

    private func play(stream: URL) {
        let asset = AVAsset(url: stream)
        let playetItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
        player = MyPlayer(playerItem: playetItem)
        player?.play()
    }
}


class MyPlayer: AVPlayer {

    override func seek(to time: CMTime, toleranceBefore: CMTime, toleranceAfter: CMTime, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        super.seek(to: time, toleranceBefore: toleranceBefore, toleranceAfter: toleranceAfter, completionHandler: completionHandler)

        print("The user did seek to: \(time)")
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work with fast forwards and rewinds which is achieved by holding the top left or top right button of the Siri Remote.